# the error improper use of Get-X has been detected and bottom overflow error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-getx

I was following a Youtube Tutorial of GETX and got this error. Do anyone know how to solve this?
and the bottom overflowed without any reason.

here is the cart total file

```
class CartTotal extends StatelessWidget {
  final CartController controller = Get.find();
  CartTotal({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: const [
              Text(
                'Total',
              ),
              Text(
                '\$controller.total',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the obx to the Row widget, and make sure you have assigned .obs in the controller

```
Obx(() => Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            const Text(
              'Total',
            ),
            Text(
              controller.title.value,
            ),
          ],
        ))
```

Comment: tried but didn't work. Do you want to see the full code? It's short

Comment: GetX solved but showing bottom overflowed by infinity pixels.

Comment: Might be with other widget wrap the body with SingleChildScrollView()


       ----     body: SingleChildScrollView( your code here )